# JointJS Draw SVG with NodeJS in backend Server

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom, jointjs

For an industrial project, we have to draw a large quantity ( ~400 / 500) of diagrams made with jointjs and export them as SVG in one PDF file.

For performance purposes, the drawing should be more efficient if it is done by NodeJS in backend Server instead of having multiple request from back to front.

I used JSDOM library to emulate a dom and draw svg but an error occurred:

```
jsdom/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:32
throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
```

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const fs = require ('fs')
const joint = require ('jointjs')
const path = require ('path')

const filepath = path.join( __dirname , './template_raccordement.html')
const content = fs.readFileSync(filepath, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
const myLibrary = fs.readFileSync("../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js", { encoding: "utf-8" });

const { window } = new JSDOM(content, {
    contentType: "text/html",
    includeNodeLocations: true,
    resources: "usable",
    storageQuota: 10000000,
    runScripts: "dangerously"
});

const $ = require('jquery')(window);

// Here to fix 'jQuery requires a window with a document' error
global.window = window
global.document = window.document

global.jQuery = $
global.$ = $

var element = $('#raccordementDiv')

console.log (element.text())

    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    const paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: element,
        model: graph,
        width: 1600,
        height: 800,
        gridSize: 1,
        interactive: true,
        async: true,
        frozen: false,
        sorting: joint.dia.Paper.sorting.APPROX,
        background: { color: '#F3F7F6' },
        //cellViewNamespace: shapes
    });

    console.log (paper)
```

After many hours on the internet to find a fix, I don't know how to do it.

I have also tested with phantomJS but this one seems too older, deprecated and hard to deal with it.

Comment: Instead of PhantomJS, have you considered `puppeteer`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ; before this afternoon, I didn't know Puppeteer.
It seems to be easier than phantomjs.

At the moment, I managed to draw a very simple jointjs element in chromium using puppeteer.
Thanks again